# Why am I getting an auth error when using Facebook Page Search API with granted permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to use the Facebook Page Search API to find public pages, in order to read their public Posts at a later date. However, even though I have the required permissions granted as per the response:

URL: `https://graph.facebook.com/pages/search?q=Facebook&fields=id,name&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN`

```
This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission 
or the 'Page Public Content Access' feature 
or the 'Page Public Metadata Access' feature.
```

The debug results of the user's access token is here:

[image: User Access Token]

I authorised my application with the requested permissions, hit the Page Search API but I still receive the above error.

What am I missing?

Comment: _"This endpoint requires the 'pages_read_engagement' permission"_ is a bit misleading here - that permission only applies to pages you have admin access to, but for arbitrary pages you are going to find via search, that will not be the case. You will need to get one of the two mentioned features approved for your app, for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, so how would you suggest generating a screencast to have the "Page Public Content Access" permission reviewed if I can't get a valid search result even while in development mode?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/searching says it should also be possible with a user access token and the app secret, the features are only necessary if you are trying to perform the search using an app token. I would assume(!)  the _"and the app secret"_ refers to making the request including an `appsecret_proof`, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/guides/secure-requests#appsecret_proof

Comment: No dice sadly, tried adding `?client_secret=APP_SECRET`, `?appsecret_proof=GENERATED_PROOF` - same error returned. 

I also tried generating the proof as per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#generate-the-proof as well (just for sanity)

Comment: facing same issue, unable to query search API even though I have the right permissions